# Is it necessary to use "then" in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

I was preparing for a SAT and stumbled on this sentence below:

> By the second half of the nineteenth century, New York City's population had surpassed the
> population of Paris, which was ***then*** around 2.5 million.

Although it doesn't sound weird to me, I would be able to understand the sentence without "then"

Is  it adding some meaning to the sentence?

Comment: Including ***then*** (or equivalents such as ***at that time***) adds nothing to the meaning, since realistically speaking there's no chance that the writer would be mentioning the population of Paris at some *different* time. It's really just a stylistic choice to include it - and if you needed to save even more space you could replace the entire sequence ***which was then*** with just ***at***.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I think that you could post your answer in the answer section below, rather than as a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can omit ***then*** in this sentence without changing the meaning.

Comment: This would be a much better answer if you explained why it doesn't change the meaning.